# Python regular expressions: match a range of numbers with a separator

Tags: python, regex

I would like the user to feed a range of numbers to be printed:
E.g:

```
27-84
```

I came up with the following regex:

```
^(?P<Begin>\d+)((-?)(?P<end>\d+)?)$
```

So it will match: `27-84` as the following groups:

```
Begin   [0-2]   `27`
2.  [2-5]   `-84`
3.  [2-3]   `-`
end [3-5]   `84`
```

Seems OK, but I would like to hear if there is a more elegant way, or if there are cavities I am overseeing.

#### clarification:

- A single number like : `27` is allowed.
- A single number with `27-`, should be understood as `27 to end`.
- A single number with `-10`, should be understood as `begin to 10`.
- A sequence with `10-27` should be understood as 10 to 27 as inclusive.

Comment: Right now the `end` part is optional, so `1-` is valid whereas `-10` is not. Is that intentional?

Comment: Also, "cavities". Heh. (SCNR)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Original answer below)*

Okay, with your clarification update, you won’t be able to make that *that* easily with regular expressions, unless you also accept just a `-` as “from beginning to end”. In that case, you could use this:

```
>>> r = re.compile('^((?P<fixed>\d+)|(?P<begin>\d+)?-(?P<end>\d+)?)$')
>>> r.match('123').groupdict()
{'begin': None, 'fixed': '123', 'end': None}
>>> r.match('123-').groupdict()
{'begin': '123', 'fixed': None, 'end': None}
>>> r.match('-456').groupdict()
{'begin': None, 'fixed': None, 'end': '456'}
>>> r.match('-').groupdict()
{'begin': None, 'fixed': None, 'end': None}
>>> r.match('123-456').groupdict()
{'begin': '123', 'fixed': None, 'end': '456'}
```

Otherwise, you will have to use more explicit cases:

```
>>> r = re.compile('^((?P<fixed>\d+)|-(?P<endonly>\d+)|(?P<begin>\d+)(?:-(?P<end>\d+)?))$')
>>> r.match('123').groupdict()
{'endonly': None, 'begin': None, 'fixed': '123', 'end': None}
>>> r.match('123-').groupdict()
{'endonly': None, 'begin': '123', 'fixed': None, 'end': None}
>>> r.match('-456').groupdict()
{'endonly': '456', 'begin': None, 'fixed': None, 'end': None}
>>> r.match('123-456').groupdict()
{'endonly': None, 'begin': '123', 'fixed': None, 'end': '456'}
>>> r.match('-') is None
True
```

As you can see, the amount of work necessary to correctly interpret the results afterwards increases in complexity.

However, I would recommend you to go away from regular expressions for this though, and do the parsing directly in Python. For example like this:

```
def parseRange (expr):
    if not expr or not re.match('^\d*-?\d*$', expr):
        raise ValueError('Not a correct range')

    # single number
    if '-' not in expr:
        return int(expr), int(expr)
    else:
        begin, end = expr.split('-')
        begin = float('-inf') if begin == '' else int(begin)
        end = float('inf') if end == '' else int(end)
        return begin, end
```

Used like this:

```
>>> parseRange('123')
(123, 123)
>>> parseRange('123-')
(123, inf)
>>> parseRange('-456')
(-inf, 456)
>>> parseRange('123-456')
(123, 456)
```

---

#### Original answer

You can just get rid of some of those capturing groups to simply it:

```
^(?P<begin>\d+)-(?P<end>\d+)$
```

This also fixes the problem that the `-` could be there without a second number and that theoretically (not practically) begin and end could be separated by nothing.

If you don’t always want to match a range but also want to allow a single number, you can put the range part in a non-capturing group. That way you don’t end up with additional groups:

```
^(?P<begin>\d+)(?:-(?P<end>\d+))?$
```

And finally, if you want to accept `to` as a separator as well, you can even do that:

```
^(?P<begin>\d+)(?:(?:-|\s+to\s+)(?P<end>\d+))?$
```

```
>>> r = re.compile('^(?P<begin>\d+)(?:-(?P<end>\d+))?$')
>>> r.match('123').groupdict()
{'begin': '123', 'end': None}
>>> r.match('123-456').groupdict()
{'begin': '123', 'end': '456'}

>>> r = re.compile('^(?P<begin>\d+)(?:(?:-|\s+to\s+)(?P<end>\d+))?$')
>>> r.match('123-456').groupdict()
{'begin': '123', 'end': '456'}
>>> r.match('123 to 456').groupdict()
{'begin': '123', 'end': '456'}
```

Answer (score 1):

To allow and correctly handle all the cases you mentioned in your edit, you need a different regex:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?P<begin>\d*)(?P<range>-?)(?P<end>\d*)$
```

The lookahead at the start is necessary to assert that there is at least one digit in the string (because `begin` or `end` can be optional, but not both).

As a verbose regex with explanations:

```
^              # Start of string
(?=.*\d)       # Assert that there is at least one digit somewhere
(?P<begin>\d*) # Match 0 or more digits --> Begin
(?P<range>-?)  # Match 0 or 1 dash
(?P<end>\d*)   # Match 0 or more digits --> End
$              # End of string
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/sI0zX9).

Comment: How do you differentiate between `123-` and `123` then?

Comment: Ah yes, we should be capturing the comma if it's there. Good point.